# get old values in a form in Colorbox before update

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, colorbox

i am new bie in code igniter .i have a data showing in tables in my view page .. in each row there is an edit button .. i want that if i clicks on the edit link  a colorbox is gonna pop up with a form in which the form is filled with old values and he then able to update it.. i have done everything in controller and model but i dont know how to use colorbox .. i visit their site also but i didnt understand much .. this is what i am doing 
 here is the form where user add the data

```
form name and id is "form" 
echo form_open('employesController/addEmployes')

        form_input();// 
        form_input();//
        form_button()
      form_close();

  this is the table where data is showing
    <td><?php echo $row->emp_name ?></td>

   <td><?php echo $row->description ?></td>



<td> <a href = "employesController/editEmploye/<?php echo  $row->emp_id ?>" id = "btn">   Edit
```

my controller

```
 function editEmploye($id){


$this->load->model('employesModel');
$data['result'] = $this->employesModel->getEditEmploye($id);
echo  json_encode($data);
  }
```

my modal

```
     function getEditEmploye($id)
{
    return $this->db->where('emp_id',$id)->get('employees')->row();
}
```

and i thing my jquery function for popup modal is going to be like that ..

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#btn").click(function(){
var $form = $("#form");
$("#").colorbox({inline:true, href:$form});


 });
   });
```

please tell me how can i get selected row values in a form in Colorbox

Answer (score 0):

Ok, `Colorbox` and `codeigniter` really work well together. I have done several projects in `CI` that have used `Colorbox`.

Colorbox will just load a url within an iframe.

so for example.

`http://localhost/mycontroller/edit`

without colorbox it would change in the current window. If you include color box class on the actual link it should open within the iframe.